# Do's and don'ts in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Where can I find a good overview of the do's and don'ts in RubyOnRails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://rails-bestpractices.com is a good site.

Comment: the rails_best_practices gem is a good tool to automatically check for a lot of these things